# How can I write this SQL query in the correct 'Codeigniter way'?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently expirementing with Codeigniter and I have a query within a model as follows;

```
function retrieve_user($user_id)
    {
        // TODO: Update this query to correct CI syntax
        $query = "SELECT user_id, username, email, banned, created, avatar, country, gender, user_level FROM users, user_profiles WHERE users.id = user_profiles.id AND users.id = ?";
        $values = array($user_id);
        return $this->db->query($query, $values)->row_array();
    }
```

This works and I'm happy with the result, however for the sake of good coding practice I'd like to write this using the documented CI format.

Can anyone please help me with this? I have read the documentation however have found myself a little puzzled at putting it into practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('user_id, username, email, banned, created, avatar, country, gender, user_level FROM users, user_profiles')->join('user_profiles','user_profiles.id = users.id')->get_where('users',array(users.id=>$user_id))->result();
```

here is the reference url:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
 $this->db->select('user_id, username, email, banned, created, avatar, country, gender, user_level');
$this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'user_profiles.id = users.id');
    $this->db->where('users.id =', 'user_profiles.id');
$this->db->where('users.id =', '?');
```

try to follow this for more information:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: looks cleaner and DRY by chaining